# Javascript RegExp finding digit grouping

Tags: javascript

I try to learn Javascript RegExp and got this RegEx somewhere:

```
"1234567890".match(/(\d{3})+(?!\d)/g) 
["234567890"] //result from log
```

I could not understand why it is like this. any help explaining this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: please don't ask questions like teach me this and that.

Comment: As the old man said "If you can't explain it to a six-year old, you really don't understand it yourself. if you can teach people to understand thing they don't ask very much. is that not stackoverflow is all about?

Comment: dear @praHoc : please see this before asking anything http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @karan Thank you for your helpng with the link!

Comment: @karan The page you linked to doesn't prohibit this kind of question in any manner. BTW such questions are pretty common on SO.

Comment: @cFreed Thank you very much for clarity, Cheer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex matches groups of digits with the condition that the group length must be a multiple of 3 and the character trailing the group cannot be a digit.

---

This is how it works:

```
(\d{3})        // match exactly 3 digits
       +       // 1 to n times
        (?!\d) // Negative lookahead - assert that the next character is not a digit
```

[More about lookaheads.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973609/3836229)

---

In your test string, the only possible match is the one returned from the `match()` call.

See the following snippet for another example:

```js
var matches = "1234foobar5678901".match(/(\d{3})+(?!\d)/g);
console.log(matches); // ["234", "678901"]
```

Comment: Thank, I still don't undertand why the result not ['123456789'] instead ['234567890']?

Comment: That's what the negative lookahead is for - `123456789` is followed by a `0`, so wouldn't satisfy the condition. `234567890` however is not followed by a digit, and covered by the regex.

Comment: Thank for example, can I say look for d*3 to N time behind (?!\d)? my head fu*k up with regex! at the moment.

Comment: I learned a lot from the link you gave! and found that Javascript did not support lookbehind! Just get my head around after 5hours!